# How do i make each vector in a 2D vector different?

Tags: c++, vector

Good evening all, I am trying to get a vector of vectors to store essentially a table of values where the second column uses the number from the first to calculate it and well, it is not working. 
I want it to store my values like:

```
    T   R
0 | 20 [R1]
1 | 30 [R2]
2 | 40 [R3]
3 | 50 [R4]
4 | 60 [R5]
[Continues until hits last number]
The numbers along the left side are the rows like Stuff[0][T] = 20, etc

So T would be vector<double>Temp and R would be vector<double>Resistance and 
they are both contained in vector<vector<double> >Stuff.
```

And so the R vector would use the values of T to calculate the resistance.

```
int main ()                                                                                         
{

    double InitTemp,FinTemp,TempIncr;
    vector <vector <double> > Stuff;

    cout << "What is the range of temperatures being tested?(Initial Final) ";
    cin >> InitTemp >> FinTemp;
    cout << "How much would you like each temperature to increment? ";
    cin >> TempIncr;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        vector <double> Temp;
        vector<double> Resistance;
        if(i == 0)
        {

            for (int j = InitTemp; j <= FinTemp; j+=TempIncr)
                Temp.push_back(j);
            Stuff.push_back(Temp);
        }

        if(i == 1)
        {

            double R=0;
            for(int k = 0; k < Temp.size();k++)
            {
                R = Temp[k]+1;
                Resistance.push_back(R);
            }
            Stuff.push_back(Resistance);
        }

    for (int i = 0; i< Stuff.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < Stuff[i].size(); j++)
            cout << Stuff[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

This piece of program will go in another larger program that uses a function to calculate the resistance but I still need to use Temp to do so which is why I have it just adding 1 to the temp as a placeholder.
My output looks like this:

```
What is the range of temperatures being tested?(Initial Final) 20 200
How much would you like each temperature to increment? 10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
110
120
130
140
150
160
170
180
190
200
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It does not output my second vector, if it even made it. Please help me understand

Comment: Why don't you use something like a vector of `std::pair<vector<double>, vector<double>>`?

Comment: As for your problem with the current code, with the input you specify, what is the *expected* output? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Or perhaps you want a vector of `std::map<double, std::vector<double>>`? It's not quite clear to me.

Comment: @Eddie: Is the value of R just 1 more than the value of Temp?

Comment: The output should be the vector of vectors to show it stores the values correctly with each row as (Temperature) (Resistance) [End Line] but it just prints out (Temperature) [End Line] right now, I am not sure if the program is calculating R and not displaying it or not displaying R because it was not calculated. 
R right now is just one more of Temp, this whole program is to make sure this part works before I put it into a much larger program so R will eventually call a function to calculate the resistance at the temperature to the left in the first vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for a `std::vector` of `std::pair<double, double>`. Then your code will become much simpler. The first `double` is `Temperature` and the second is `Resistance`. From what I see in your code, `Resistance` is just 1 added to `Temperature`. In that case the following code should work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double InitTemp, FinTemp, TempIncr;
    vector <pair<double, double > > Stuff;

    cout << "What is the range of temperatures being tested?(Initial Final) ";
    cin >> InitTemp >> FinTemp;
    cout << "How much would you like each temperature to increment? ";
    cin >> TempIncr;

    for (int j = InitTemp; j <= FinTemp; j += TempIncr)             
        Stuff.emplace_back(j, j+1);

    for (int i = 0; i < Stuff.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << Stuff[i].first << ", " << Stuff[i].second << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The output of R was supposed to be that you can still call a value from vector Temp to show it works, but i replaced "j+1" with a function call plus its needed parameters and it works so thank you :) I actually did not know about emplace_back, my C++ teacher only taught us the push_back one. I also learned everything I know about vectors in the last ~5 hours because its extra credit to use them instead of arrays so thank you for showing me the '.first' and the pair function.